# java.lang.NullPointerException at object instantiation

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, struts

My application uses struts and spring frameworks. I have a class `FormA` which has an autowired property in it. When I try to instantiate it while writing unit tests I get a Null Pointer Exception. Here is my code.

**My ClassA:**

```
public class FormA{
    private String propertyOne;
    @Autowired
    private ServiceClass service;

    public FormA(){
    }
}
```

My unit test method:

```
@Test
public void testFormA(){
FormA classObj = new FormA();    
}
```

Comment: did you put service or component annotation in ServiceClass?

Comment: Yes I did put the service annotation.

Comment: @user2191903  Have you solved this problem? If you have solve it, How have you done?

Answer (score 3):

`@Autowired` only works when object life cycle is managed by Spring.

You'll need to run your tests with `@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)`, and instead of instantiating `FormA` manually, inject it in the test class as well, using `@Autowired`.

Comment: Can we use Spring to autowire an object the life cycle of which *is not* managed by Spring?

Comment: No. You'll need to register it with Spring using `@Service` or `@Component` annotations (or using the xml configuration), then you'll be able to autowire them.

Comment: Struts actions don't use these annotations but I'm able to autowire them.

Comment: I'm not aware of the way Struts works with Spring, but I expect those actions are somehow registered to be managed by Spring and that's why you're able to autowire them. I was just saying you can't have an object from outside the context autowired by Spring.

Comment: It seems you don't know Struts, nor Spring.

Comment: @RomanC Please explain that statement. 
BTW, You're not contributing to answering OP's question at all.

Comment: You said *I'm not aware of the way Struts works with Spring*. No, actions are not registered or configured in the Spring context (not managed by Spring), they even don't have any Spring annotation, however actions can be aoutowired by Spring. And you said I can't do it, that is wrong I do it everyday.

Comment: Care to elaborate, how exactly is that happening?

Comment: Don't like to do it, because it's off-topic, however you can read [some](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18065931/573032) of my answers or ask a question that community liked to answer.

Answer (score 1):

When you create an object by new, autowire\inject don't work...

as workaround you can try this:

create your template bean of NotesPanel

```
<bean id="notesPanel" class="..." scope="prototype">
    <!-- collaborators and configuration for this bean go here -->
</bean>
```

and create an istance in this way

```
applicationContext.getBean("notesPanel");
```

**PROTOTYPE** : This scopes a single bean definition to have any number of object instances.

anyway a unit test should be

**Test class**

```
@RunWith( SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class )
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "classpath:META-INF/your-spring-context.xml" })
public class UserServiceTest extends AbstractJUnit4SpringContextTests {

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @Test
    public void testName() throws Exception {
        List<UserEntity> userEntities = userService.getAllUsers();

        Assert.assertNotNull(userEntities);
    }
}
```

**your-spring-context.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" 
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd">

    <bean id="userService" class="java.package.UserServiceImpl"/>

</beans>
```

Comment: Don't work? Can you read [my comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26800131/java-lang-nullpointerexception-at-object-instantiation/26800199#comment42174362_26800199) to below post?

Comment: When you create an object in this way `FormA classObj = new FormA();` all @Autowired inside that class does not injected.

Comment: Can't we create an object this way?

Comment: If you want use inside @Autowired I suggest to retrive that bean from the context as prototype bean.

Comment: The bean is not in the context, is it required the bean to be in the context?

Comment: Yes it is, If you want gain all spring benefits (IoC, Dependency Injection).

Comment: Struts don't need those benefits, because it's running its own container. Can't I use Struts with Spring?

Comment: Yes you can, there are many other questions about Spring and Struts. [See Here for example](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19599849/3364187)

Comment: This questions are useless until they post `struts.xml`. Like your answer is useless until you show how `FormA` object is instantiated if it's *not managed* by Spring. Of course it needs to be autowired, but you said *Yes it is* on my question *The bean is not in the context, is it required the bean to be in the context?*.